# Firefox extension - accessing the content of a cross-origin iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, firefox-addon

I am building a little firefox browser extension to save a web page to an epub file.

My target website "A" basically loads an iframe containing the content from domain "B" in my page, like this

```
<body>
  <p>Some content</p>
   <iframe>
    (Data from domain B)
   </iframe>
</body>
```

From the page, i can `document.getElement` the iframe, but then i have no way to access its content. The object is restricted, and i have no possibilities to access it further (i get the error about how it's a cross-origin object). Since i don't control the website, i can't possibly add a `postMessage()` logic in the pages.

I get that it's a security feature, but i don't want to alter the original object; just manipulate a copy of it. Is there some way to circumvent this ?

Thanks

Comment: If I understand correctly,  don't think you can do what you want - if you could read the contents of a window that you don't own or have access to, you could also presumably read personal data off of any site (e.g. load gmail into a hidden iframe, hope they're logged in, and steal all their secrets). What you _might_ be able to do is require access to domain B for the extension and insert a script in there, allowing you to use `postMessage`.

Comment: @vrugtehagel Ah that's what i thought. Well, since the goal of this is to work as a browser addon, it makes the whole thing impossible. I tought that maybe my script could run with more permissions, since the user installs it and all